# Behavior of Python 2.7's ZipFile when zipping files

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I'm currently working with python 2.7's ZipFile. I have been running into memory issues zipping multiple files to send to the user.

When I have code:

```
fp = open('myzip.zip', 'w')
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(fp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for filepath in filepaths:
   archive.write(filepath)
archive.close()
```

Does Python load all those files into memory at some point? I would have expected Python to stream the contents of the files into the zip, but I'm not sure that that is the case.

Comment: Looks like the module reads in 8 * 1024 characters into memory at a time https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py#l1179

Comment: `ZipFile.write()` doesn't consume much memory. As mentioned it uses modest block sizes and those are freed as they are used. Is the program itself growing large or do you mean something else by memory issues? The operating system caches writes so it'll be fast until the OS starts committing the data. Then things may bog down a bit.

Comment: Interesting, OK this may be a red herring

Answer (score 0):

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849328/how-to-zip-a-very-large-file-in-python) (both by same user) suggests that it's all done in memory. They provide a link to a modified library [EnhancedZipFile](https://github.com/AchoArnold/EnhancedZipFile) that sounds like it works as you desire, however it doesn't seem to have had much activity on the project.

If you're not dependent on zip specifically, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519016/66349) implies that the bzip library can handle large files.

Comment: That author was using `writestr` because he wanted to modify the name of the file written. That method requires reading the entire file into memory, but method used here does not. As of python 3.6, `ZipFile.open` supports write mode... so this was finally fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Python will hold all the files you iterate over in memory, there is no way i can think of to bypass that except for calling an executable that will do the job for you on the operating system.

Comment: Check out the documentation for `ZipFile.write`. Those are just filenames, not file content. OP is iterating an existing list... no appreciable hit there.